# Why is condition not working when I select more than 10 days?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datepicker

This is my code what i am trying is to make a datepicker to select number of days selected without Saturday and Friday it is working correctly but when I select more than one weekend (2 Friday or 2 sat) and the last day is weekend it escapes the last weekend like if day 30 is Saturday and i select from day 1 to day 30 it gives me 23 how ever if I select 1 to 28 it gives me 22.

```
var date = new Date();
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
$('#picker').daterangepicker({
  "linkedCalendars": true,
  "showCustomRangeLabel": false,
  "startDate": date.getDate(),
  "endDate": tomorrow,
  "cancelClass": "btn-danger",
  "minDate": date.getDate(),
  "opens": "center",
  "autoApply": true
}, function(start, end) {
  function parseDate(str) {
    var mdy = str.split('-');
    var x = new Date("'" + mdy[0] + "-" + mdy[1] + "-" + mdy[2]);
    return x;
  }
  var between = [];

  function datediff(first, second) {
    var currentDate = new Date(first);
    between = [];
    while (currentDate <= second) {
      between.push("'" + currentDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + currentDate.getDate() + "'");
      currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
    }
    //return Math.round((second-first)/(1000*60*60*24))+1;
  }
  datediff(parseDate(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')), parseDate(end.format('YYYY-MM-DD')));
  var s = "",
    n = "",
    fri = "",
    sat = "",
    i;
  var number = between.length;

  function getweekend() {
    for (i = 0; i <= number + 1; i++) {
      s = new Date(between[i]);
      n = s.getDay();
      fri = (n === 5);
      sat = (n === 6);
      if (fri) {
        console.log("fri");
        number = number - 1;
        continue;
      } else if (sat) {
        console.log("sat");
        number = number - 1;
        continue;
      } else {
        console.log(n);
        continue;
      }
    }
    console.log("after minus:" + number);
  }
  console.log("plus minus:" + number);
  getweekend();
});
```

Comment: Why are you concatenating a single quote to the beginning of the date? That's not part of date syntax.

Comment: The `for` loop is going outside the `between` array. The condition should be `i < number`. Array indexes go from `0` to `number-1`, not `number+1`.

Comment: Why are you splitting `str` on `-` characters and then putting it back together with the same delimiter? Why not just `return str`?

Comment: Well first of all, that is a very inefficient way to do what you want. Think about it. There are always 5 non-weekend days in a week (though to me, Saturday and Sunday are weekend days, not Friday and Saturday, but whatever). In working out how many working days there are between two dates, you only need to know how many full weeks the date range contains, and then work out whether or not you need to subtract some days based on the ends of the selected period being weekend days...